# How to send an event to a particular user? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am building one to one chat with laravel and pusher.I am trying to send event only to the person one is talking to but not able to do so.Event is send to all ,don't know what is the issue.

```
<ul class="list" id="friend">
      @foreach(Auth::user()->friends() as $f)
        <li  data-friend="{{$f->id}}" class="clearfix" style="cursor: pointer">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/195612/chat_avatar_01.jpg" alt="avatar" />
          <div class="about">
            <div class="name">{{$f->firstname}}</div>
            <div class="status">
              <i class="fa fa-circle online"></i> online
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
```

textarea:

```
<div class="chat-message clearfix">
        <textarea name="message-to-send" id="message-to-send" placeholder ="Type your message" rows="3"></textarea>

        <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>

        <button id="send" data-userid="{{Auth::user()->id}}">Send</button>

      </div>
```

script:

```
<script>
      b={!!json_encode(Auth::user()->id)!!};
     pusher=new Pusher('******',{
    cluster:'ap1'
   });
  channel=pusher.subscribe('user'+b);

    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#friend li').click(function(){
   var f=$(this).attr('data-friend');
    $('#send').click(function(){
    var userid=$(this).attr('data-userid');
    var message=$('#message-to-send').val();

      $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'/chat2/'+message+'/'+f,
        success:function(response){
          console.log('dshfgjhgdhjs');
        }
      })
  });
});
 });
     channel.bind('App\\Events\\chat2', function(e){
      console.log(e);
     } );
  </script>
```

route:

```
Route::get('/chat2/{message}/{friend}',function($message,$friend){

     event(new chat2(Auth::user(),$message,$friend));

});
```

event:

```
class chat2 implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $message;
    public $friend;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user,$message,$friend)
    {
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->message=$message;
        $this->friend=$friend;//
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('user'.$this->friend);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of "Event is send to all" do you perhaps mean "Event is sent to all"?

Comment: @MhluziBhaka yes!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at private broadcast channels. Laravel supports authenticated private channels for broadcast events.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

Once you have the user listening on a private channel, you can send events only to that channel.